# XSLT1.0 copy node content from specific tags when transforming XML data

Tags: python, xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XSLT transformation file to convert an XML file to another format. The source XML has many formating tags that are incompatible with the destination stylesheet. Then, I need to read the content of some tags and pass the element content.

Here is the XSLT1.0 transformation code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var1_initial" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="procstep">
            <procl>
                <xsl:variable name="var11_cur" select="."/>
                <procstep>
                    <xsl:attribute name="time">1</xsl:attribute>
                    <title>
                        <xsl:for-each select="(./proct/node())[./self::text()]">
                            <xsl:variable name="var12_filter" select="."/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(string(.))"/>
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </title>
                </procstep>
            </procl>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is an example source data:

```
<procl>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Connect the lifts together.</br>Lift the vehicle.</proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Remove the screws.</br>Remove the plates.</proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Remove the nuts and washers.</br>Remove the shield.</proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Secure the exhaust pipe.</br>Install a strap.</br>Apply torque of <hp1>25 Nm</hp1>.</proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Install the screws and nuts.</br>Use tool <hp2>256256</hp2> to fix the clamp.</proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Install the nuts and screws.</br>Assemble the member in the following order:
            <table>
                <tgroup cols="2" colsep="1" rowsep="1">
                    <colspec colwidth="132.38*"/>
                    <colspec colwidth="132.10*"/>
                    <thead>
                        <row>
                            <entry align="left" valign="top">Value</entry>
                            <entry align="left" valign="top">Position</entry>
                        </row>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <row>
                            <entry align="left" valign="top">25</entry>
                            <entry align="left" valign="top">Superior</entry>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <entry align="left" valign="top">12</entry>
                            <entry align="left" valign="top">Inferior</entry>
                        </row>
                    </tbody>
                </tgroup>
            </table>
        </proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Lower the vehicle.</proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Mark the <hp1>torque value</hp1> in the data sheet.</proct>
    </procstep>
</procl>
```

Where I have `<hp0>`, `<hp1>`, `<hp2>` and `<hp3>` as formating tags (bold, italc, underline and enphatized). The tag `</br>` is a brake line, and will be removed by the normalize-space option.

The destination code must keep the element inside `<hp*>` and `</hp*>`, but must delete the tags.
I try to add all content, but the destination stylesheet doesn't allow `<hp*>` tags. It doesn't allow another tags, like table content. Using a XPath would include the  content, that I need to ignore.

The result code must be:

```
<procl>
    <procstep>
        <title>Connect the lifts together. Lift the vehicle. </title>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <title>Remove the screws. Remove the plates. </title>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <title>Remove the nuts and washers. Remove the shield. </title>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <title>Secure the exhaust pipe. Install a strap. Apply torque of 25 Nm. </title>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <title>Install the screws and nuts. Use tool 256256 to fix the clamp. </title>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <title>Install the nuts and screws. Assemble the member in the following order: </title>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <title>Lower the vehicle. </title>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <title>Mark the torque value in the data sheet. </title>
    </procstep>
</procl>
```

I'm using the XSLT inside a Python app with LET.XSLT lirary, them I am limited to use XSLT1.0. My XSLT code and source data is more complex. I try to simplify here to focus only in the transformation of `<proct>` data.

So, the question is: how to pass the conten inside `<hp*></hp*>` and not to another child nodes under `<proct></proct>`?
Maybe the question is very simple to you, but I am a newbie in XSLT transformations.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for one thing, your output could be produced quite simply using only this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/procl | procstep">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="proct">
    <title>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </title>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(starts-with(name(), 'hp'))]" priority="-1"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only difference between the actual result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<procl>
   <procstep>
      <title>Connect the lifts together. Lift the vehicle.</title>
   </procstep>
   <procstep>
      <title>Remove the screws. Remove the plates.</title>
   </procstep>
   <procstep>
      <title>Remove the nuts and washers. Remove the shield.</title>
   </procstep>
   <procstep>
      <title>Secure the exhaust pipe. Install a strap. Apply torque of 25 Nm.</title>
   </procstep>
   <procstep>
      <title>Install the screws and nuts. Use tool 256256 to fix the clamp.</title>
   </procstep>
   <procstep>
      <title>Install the nuts and screws. Assemble the member in the following order:
            </title>
   </procstep>
   <procstep>
      <title>Lower the vehicle.</title>
   </procstep>
   <procstep>
      <title>Mark the torque value in the data sheet.</title>
   </procstep>
</procl>
```

and the expected output is the extra white space after `"Assemble the member in the following order:"`.

You could try to remove it by using `normalize-space()` -  but if you apply it globally to all text nodes passed to the output (as suggested above), you will also destroy existing spaces which may exist around the `hp*` formatting elements. Trying to restore these arbitrarily may lead to a result that is different from the original text - e.g. when only a part of a word is formatted. If there is a way to identify such problematic text nodes (such as having an immediately following `table` sibling), that would be preferable, IMHO. Alternatively, you could add another pass of processing and apply `normalize-space()` to the `title` elements created in the first pass.

Comment: Very good approach! It is useful when we have variable tags (hp0, hp1, ... hpn). Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

The input XML is not well-formed. I had to fix it.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<procl>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Connect the lifts together.<br/>Lift the vehicle.</proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Remove the screws.<br/>Remove the plates.</proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Remove the nuts and washers.<br/>Remove the shield.</proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Secure the exhaust pipe.<br/>Install a strap.<br/>Apply torque of <hp1>25 Nm</hp1>.</proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Install the screws and nuts.<br/>Use tool <hp2>256256</hp2> to fix the clamp.</proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Install the nuts and screws.<br/>Assemble the member in the following order:
            <table>
                <tgroup cols="2" colsep="1" rowsep="1">
                    <colspec colwidth="132.38*"/>
                    <colspec colwidth="132.10*"/>
                    <thead>
                        <row>
                            <entry align="left" valign="top">Value</entry>
                            <entry align="left" valign="top">Position</entry>
                        </row>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <row>
                            <entry align="left" valign="top">25</entry>
                            <entry align="left" valign="top">Superior</entry>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <entry align="left" valign="top">12</entry>
                            <entry align="left" valign="top">Inferior</entry>
                        </row>
                    </tbody>
                </tgroup>
            </table>
        </proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Lower the vehicle.</proct>
    </procstep>
    <procstep>
        <proct>Mark the <hp1>torque value</hp1> in the data sheet.</proct>
    </procstep>
</procl>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="proct">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </title>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="hp1|hp2">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table"/>
    <xsl:template match="br"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<procl>
  <procstep>
    <title>Connect the lifts together.Lift the vehicle.</title>
  </procstep>
  <procstep>
    <title>Remove the screws.Remove the plates.</title>
  </procstep>
  <procstep>
    <title>Remove the nuts and washers.Remove the shield.</title>
  </procstep>
  <procstep>
    <title>Secure the exhaust pipe.Install a strap.Apply torque of 25 Nm .</title>
  </procstep>
  <procstep>
    <title>Install the screws and nuts.Use tool 256256 to fix the clamp.</title>
  </procstep>
  <procstep>
    <title>Install the nuts and screws.Assemble the member in the following order:</title>
  </procstep>
  <procstep>
    <title>Lower the vehicle.</title>
  </procstep>
  <procstep>
    <title>Mark the torque value in the data sheet.</title>
  </procstep>
</procl>
```

Comment: @Parfait, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I need to have in the output XML the content inside <hp1> and <hp2> tags. For example, in the 4th line, I need that the converted tag is`<title>Secure the exhaust pipe. Install a strap.Apply torque of 25 Nm.</title>`. (with the text inside <hp2>...</hp2>, but without the tags).

Comment: I adjusted the answer. Please give it a shot.

Comment: Perfect! I made some changes in the code and now it is inside the app. Thank you!